# Why can't I call an overloaded function in this manner?

Tags: typescript, overloading

Take this example of function overloading:

```
function pickCard(x: {suit: string; card: number; }[]): number;
function pickCard(x: number): {suit: string; card: number; };
function pickCard(x): any {
      /* ... */
}
```

In the [Handbook](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Functions.md#overloads) it says:

> Note that the `function pickCard(x): any` piece is not part of the
>   overload list, so it only has two overloads: one that takes an object
>   and one that takes a number. Calling pickCard with any other parameter
>   types would cause an error.

Therefore I cannot call `pickCard("test");`. It throws an error.

If `pickCard(x)` is not a valid function signature, then why do we have to write it? What is the benefit of having it around? Is there a use case that I am not thinking of?

Check out the [playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20pickCard(x%3A%20%7Bsuit%3A%20string%3B%20card%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%5B%5D)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0Afunction%20pickCard(x%3A%20number)%3A%20%7Bsuit%3A%20string%3B%20card%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20pickCard(x)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%09%2F*%20...%20*%2F%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ApickCard(%22test%22)%3B)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35552201/2788872) might be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are just signatures, to specify what are the different options are for calling the function.

The third is the actual function definition, and it just receives one argument and returns any.
In it you implement the actual logic, check what are the types that the function received and return the appropriate value according to the passed params.

For example:

```
function a(str: string): string;
function a(num: number): number;
function a(value: any): any {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        return (parseInt(value) * 2).toString();
    } else {
        return value * 2;
    }
}

a("3"); // should be "6"
a(3); // should be 6
a(true); // error
```

You need to have the third because otherwise you'll need to use one of the other signatures as the actual function definition.
If you choose the first then the parameter is a string not a number, if you go with the 2nd one then the parameter is a number not a string.
That's why the 3rd one is there, it figures out what the actual params that were passed in and based on that carries it's logic.

You can also have different number of properties:

```
function b(a: number): number;
function b(a: number, b: number): number;
function b(...args: number[]): any {
    if (args.length == 1) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Which is usually the scenario in which you'll use different signatures, cuz for same number of params with different types you can simply:

```
function a(value: string | number): any {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        return (parseInt(value) * 2).toString();
    } else {
        return value * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this and for the bonus at the end.